# Big O of n^1.001 vs n*log n / log 2?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

This question is throwing me for a loop, and I hope StackOverflow is the right place to ask this. The question asks

```
n^1.001 = O(n log n) (log is base 2)
```

in other words, does n log n grow faster than n^1.001.

I keep going around in circles on this one. I graphed n^1.001 vs log n (I took out n since n is on both sides of the equation). I graphed them up to about 10^32 or so before my program crashed, and even up to there, n^0.001 had not even reached 2, whereas log n was much larger. However, I wonder, and haven't been able to prove either way, that eventually, n^1.001 will pick up and start growing a lot faster than n log n, since it has an exponent larger than 1.

Is this correct? Which has a larger growth function?

Comment: `n^(1+ε) > nlog(n) for all ε > 0, n sufficiently large`.

Comment: I'd imagine n^.001 would take a long time to reach 2, but n^1.001 probably takes quite a bit less time.  Was that a typo?

Comment: See the [orders of common functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions). "The slower-growing functions are *generally* listed first" - anyway, a handy guideline.

Comment: Think about the fact that `n^(1/2) > log(n) for n > 10`, `n^(1/4) > log(n) for n > 100`, `n^(1/8) > log(n) for n > 10000`, etc. It's easy to extrapolate that `n^ε > log(n) for all ε > 0, n sufficiently large`.

Comment: @Namfuak I got confused and didn't know how to word the rest of the question. It was definitely a logical error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Think about the fact that:

```
n^(1/2) > log(n) for n > 10,
n^(1/4) > log(n) for n > 100,
n^(1/8) > log(n) for n > 10000, etc.
```

It's easy to extrapolate that `n^ε > log(n) for all ε > 0, n sufficiently large`. Hope that Helps!